# Conditional Queries

Tags: mysql

Having a little trouble with this question:
Using the two tables below, create a subquery or join statement that shows the player, Team, and No in the Player_PROFILE table for all players coached by Fisher.

[image]

I came up with the following SQL code but I'm not sure how to finish it or if its even right:

```
SELECT PLAYER_PROFILE.Player, PLAYER_PROFILE.Team,
PLAYER_PROFILE.No
FROM PLAYER_PROFILE
INNER JOIN PLAYER_DETAIL
ON......
```

Comment: WIll player names be unique?

Answer (score 1):

Isnt it this - or am I missing something in your question

```
SELECT PLAYER_PROFILE.Player, PLAYER_PROFILE.Team, PLAYER_PROFILE.No
FROM PLAYER_PROFILE
INNER JOIN PLAYER_DETAIL ON PLAYER_PROFILE.Player=PLAYER_DETAIL.Player
WHERE PLAYER_DETAIL.Coach = 'Fisher';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT PLAYER_PROFILE.Player, PLAYER_PROFILE.Team,
PLAYER_PROFILE.No
FROM PLAYER_PROFILE
INNER JOIN PLAYER_DETAIL
ON PLAYER_PROFILE.Player = PLAYER_DETAIL.Player
WHERE PLAYER_DETAIL.Coach = "Fisher"
```

You do the inner join (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) on the player name because you need some piece of data that is unique for each player ... normally this would be some sort of ID (number/guid) but in the case of your data, it is the player name.

Answer (score 1):

Since both the tables only have `Player` as common field, so the query would be:

```
SELECT PLAYER_PROFILE.Player, PLAYER_PROFILE.Team,
PLAYER_PROFILE.No
FROM PLAYER_PROFILE
INNER JOIN PLAYER_DETAIL
ON PLAYER_PROFILE.Player = PLAYER_DETAIL.Player
WHERE PLAYER_DETAIL.Coach = 'Fisher'
```

Explanation: The above query will join the results of both the tables based on `PLAYER` name and will filter result where `Coach` is **Fisher**

If you could change table structure then I would suggest you to have `PLAERY_ID` field in both the tables so as to uniquely identify a player instead of `Player` column.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
`PLAYER_PROFILE`.`Player`,
`PLAYER_PROFILE`.`Team`,
`PLAYER_PROFILE`.`No`
FROM
`PLAYER_PROFILE`
INNER JOIN
`PLAYER_DETAIL`
ON
`PLAYER_DETAIL`.`Player`=`PLAYER_PROFILE`.`Player`
WHERE
`PLAYER_DETAIL`.`Coach`="Fisher";
```

Different players could have identical names, so it would be better to use a unique ID for each player and join on those values.

Comment: Don't forget this _"all players coached by Fisher. "_